# Running Unix shell script with batch file to download files from WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, unix, sftp, winscp

I am trying to download a file from WinSCP through batch file. I am able to download the file if I enter the file name in the batch file.

But I need to enter the file name dynamically (i.e., file name has to be entered at run time).

Here is my code

```bat
cd\Users\Desktop\WinSCP
winscp.com /ini=null /script=C:\Users\Desktop\test.txt
open sftp://username:password@hostname/
$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" username@hostname
cd /log
get test.log C:\Users\Desktop\Downloading_logs\
```

here `Test.log` is the file name I am providing in the batch file.

Please suggest a way to enter the file name dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The batch file is just nonsense. The `open`, `cd` and `get` should be in the `test.txt`, not in the batch file. What is `$ ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

Use an argument for the *batch* file

Code (*script_with_arg.bat*):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions

if "%~1" equ "" (
    echo "Please provide a file name"
    goto :eof
)

cd\Users\Desktop\WinSCP
winscp.com /ini=null /script=C:\Users\Desktop\test.txt
open sftp://username:password@hostname/
$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" username@hostname
cd /log
get "%~1" C:\Users\Desktop\Downloading_logs\

echo "Done"
```

**Notes**:

- It's the most straightforward way to do this
- The argument is referred to as `"%~1"`. Check [[SS64]: Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for more details
- The `if` clause at the beginning is to verify if the argument was provided, if not simply display an error message and exit
- When dealing with paths, it's always better to *dblquote* them, as a *SPACE* in the path might completely mess things up

Other ways:

- Use an environment variable (instead of the argument) set from outside the script
- Let the user input the file name (via `set /p`) from the script, as pointed by @ramu246 's comment (I missed this one :) )

***@EDIT0***:

- After looking at @MartinPrikryl's comment, and doing some tests, it turns out that your *.bat* file is total crap (so is mine, since it's based on yours)
- However, the fix is still OK, even if it doesn't work (because I applied it blindly - check the previous bullet)

I did some changes, and below is a version that **really works** (of course the sensitive data has been altered).

*script.bat*:

```bat
@echo off

if "%~1" equ "" (
    echo "Please provide a file name"
    goto :eof
)

winscp.com /ini=winscp_cfg.ini /script=winscp_script.txt /parameter "%~1"
echo "Done"
```

*winscp_script.txt*:

```bat
echo Received argument: "%1%"
open sftp://cfati:password@127.0.0.1:22001/
cd /tmp
get "%1%" .\"%1%"
exit
```

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>where winscp
> c:\Install\x86\WinSCP\WinSCP\AllVers\WinSCP.com
> c:\Install\x86\WinSCP\WinSCP\AllVers\WinSCP.exe
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>dir /b
> script.bat
> winscp_script.txt
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>script.bat "test with spaces.log"
> Received argument: "test with spaces.log"
> Searching for host...
> Connecting to host...
> Authenticating...
> Continue connecting to an unknown server and add its host key to a cache?
>
> The server's host key was not found in the cache. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.
>
> The server's Ed25519 key details are:
>
>     Algorithm:  ssh-ed25519 256
>     SHA-256:    M/iFTnSbi0k4VEcd8I75GiO7t6gza6RL99Pkh+bz4AQ=
>     MD5:        8f:2f:f0:4a:ed:41:aa:e6:61:fa:5d:1f:f4:5b:c0:37
>
> If you trust this host, press Yes. To connect without adding host key to the cache, press No. To abandon the connection press Cancel.
> In scripting, you should use a -hostkey switch to configure the expected host key.
> (Y)es, (N)o, C(a)ncel (8 s), (C)opy Key, (P)aste key: Yes
> Using username "cfati".
> Authenticating with pre-entered password.
> Authenticated.
> Starting the session...
> Session started.
> Active session: [1] cfati@127.0.0.1
> /tmp
> test with spaces.log      |            6 B |    0.0 KB/s | binary | 100%
> "Done"
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>dir /b
> script.bat
> test with spaces.log
> winscp_cfg.ini
> winscp_script.txt
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>del /q "test with spaces.log"
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>dir /b
> script.bat
> winscp_cfg.ini
> winscp_script.txt
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>script.bat "test with spaces.log"
> Received argument: "test with spaces.log"
> Searching for host...
> Connecting to host...
> Authenticating...
> Using username "cfati".
> Authenticating with pre-entered password.
> Authenticated.
> Starting the session...
> Session started.
> Active session: [1] cfati@127.0.0.1
> /tmp
> test with spaces.log      |            6 B |    0.0 KB/s | binary | 100%
> "Done"
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047989047>dir /b
> script.bat
> test with spaces.log
> winscp_cfg.ini
> winscp_script.txt
> ```

**Notes**:

- This time I'm using my own paths
- The *.ini* file (*winscp_cfg.ini*) is required in order to pass the host's fingerprint. It's also possible to pass `-hostkey` argument for `open` command ([[WinSCP]: open](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open)), but I wasn't successful (I didn't try too much either)

  - As you can see in the output, 1<sup>st</sup> time it requires user confirmation (`(Y)es, (N)o, C(a)ncel....`), in order to generate the file, and next times it simply uses it
  - Same thing happened for you (I assume that you wanted to skip the *.ini* file name), but due to a mistake: *Ux*'s */dev/null* equivalent in *Win* is ***nul*** (**single l**), so *winscp_cfg.ini* for your case was a file called *null*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.

i also tried this option

set /p id="Enter syslog name: "
echo %id% 
cd\Users\Desktop\WinSCP
winscp.com /ini=null /script=C:\Users\Desktop\test.txt
open sftp://username:password@hostname/
$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" username@hostname
cd /log
get %id% C:\Users\Desktop\Downloading_logs\

it worked for me

Comment: That's one other way. Don't know how did I forget about this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: Bear in mind, that although it might be the easiest way, the `set /p` approach it's not scalable, if you would need to run the script many times upon one file (or a list of files) entering the file name every time will easily become annoying (I'd say 20 times per day), while if running from console, just pressing the *Up arrow* on the keyboard and you'll have the previous command run. Also, if you want to automate stuff, user input is a NO GO. So, I'd suggest to go with the argument (you could create a wrapper that waits for user input, but the core implementation should be parametrized).

Comment: Hello all...I have  another question related to this.

The above script is running in my machine where it uses my ID and password.  

I don't want to share this bat files to my team. but they make use of this batch file to get the files. something like from their machine, they have to provide the server name and syslog file name, then they should able to downlaod the file

 I have one option encryption method.
Is there any other method to do this

Comment: You mean you don't want to share the *winscp* script. It's understood you don't want to share your password with other people, and you don't have to. Just let everyone copy it on their machines and fill their credentials. Or you could enable passwordless ssh on the *Lnx* machine, and create a restricted user to share with your colleagues. But without the limitations/reasons I can't tell you more. Also i think it could be possible due to some *PowerShell* script to let the users access the script on your computer (without getting to its content), but that's a totally different question.

Comment: so let me re-phrase the question.

A bat file which uses my credentials running in my machine. To run this Bat file, it requires additional software and server permission. That software is only available in my machine. we can't install that in all machines. Also the server permission we should not provide to all members

in this case, how can other members utilize this Bat file being kept that bat file in my machine. (I can't use encryption  method as it still requires software. )

please suggest any other way

Comment: Ok, this is a  requirement that doesn't have anything to do with the original question. I should have replied to your previous comment: if you have another question, please submit one. Because, as I said the 2 questions (even if they are 2 parts of your bigger problem) are unrelated.